# Download multiple files using MVVM-WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, webclient

At first I made an application that downloads a file from the entered link and displays information about progress, speed, etc. When I decided to change the application to download several files at the same time, I ran into a problem. So, in the interface there is a listbox in which there are several objects. When you select one of the objects and enter the link to the file, it should start downloading. When selecting another object, information about the previous object should change to the information of the selected one. I can also enter a link to the file there and then track the downloads of the two files by switching between objects. However, when switching information does not change. How to implement it?

Model:

```
public class Model
{
    public WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    public Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    public event Action<long> FileSizeChanged;
    public event Action<long, TimeSpan> DownloadBytesChanged;
    public event Action<double> ProgressPercentageChanged;
    public event Action DownloadComplete;

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void DownloadFile(string url, bool openAfterDownload)
    {
        if (webClient.IsBusy)
            throw new Exception("The client is busy");
        try
        {
            var startDownloading = DateTime.UtcNow;
            webClient.Proxy = null;
            if (!SelectFolder(Path.GetFileName(url)+Path.GetExtension(url), out var filePath))
                throw DownloadingError();
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, args) =>
            {
                ProgressPercentageChanged?.Invoke(args.ProgressPercentage);
                FileSizeChanged?.Invoke(args.TotalBytesToReceive);
                DownloadBytesChanged?.Invoke(args.BytesReceived, DateTime.UtcNow - startDownloading);
                if (args.ProgressPercentage >= 100 && openAfterDownload)
                    Process.Start(filePath);
            };
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (o, args) => DownloadComplete?.Invoke();
            stopWatch.Start();
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw DownloadingError();
        }
    }

    public void CancelDownloading()
    {
        webClient.CancelAsync();
        webClient.Dispose();
        DownloadComplete?.Invoke();
    }

    private static Exception DownloadingError()
        => new Exception("Downloading error!");

    private static bool SelectFolder(string fileName, out string filePath)
    {
        var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
        {
            InitialDirectory = "c:\\",
            FileName = fileName,
            Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*"
        };
        filePath = "";
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() != true) return false;
        filePath = saveFileDialog.FileName;
        return true;
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string url;
    private RelayCommand downloadCommand;
    private RelayCommand cancelCommand;
    private double progressBarValue;
    private string bytesReceived;
    private string bytesTotal;
    private string speed;
    private string time;
    private string error;
    private long totalBytes;
    private Model selectedGame;
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Games { get; set; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        Games = new ObservableCollection<Model>();

        Model Game1 = new Model { Name = "Name1" };
        Model Game2 = new Model { Name = "Name2" };

        Game1.FileSizeChanged += bytes => BytesTotal = PrettyBytes(totalBytes = bytes);
        Game1.DownloadBytesChanged += (bytes, time) =>
        {
            BytesReceived = PrettyBytes(bytes);
            Speed = DownloadingSpeed(bytes, time);
            Time = DownloadingTime(bytes, totalBytes, time);
        };
        Game1.ProgressPercentageChanged += percentage => ProgressBarValue = percentage;
        Game1.DownloadComplete += () =>
        {
            BytesReceived = "";
            BytesTotal = "";
            Speed = "";
            Time = "";
            ProgressBarValue = 0;
        };

        Game2.FileSizeChanged += bytes => BytesTotal = PrettyBytes(totalBytes = bytes);
        Game2.DownloadBytesChanged += (bytes, time) =>
        {
            BytesReceived = PrettyBytes(bytes);
            Speed = DownloadingSpeed(bytes, time);
            Time = DownloadingTime(bytes, totalBytes, time);
        };
        Game2.ProgressPercentageChanged += percentage => ProgressBarValue = percentage;
        Game2.DownloadComplete += () =>
        {
            BytesReceived = "";
            BytesTotal = "";
            Speed = "";
            Time = "";
            ProgressBarValue = 0;
        };
        Games.Add(Game1);
        Games.Add(Game2);
    }

    public Model SelectedGame
    {
        get => selectedGame;
        set
        {
            if (value == selectedGame) return; 
            selectedGame = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedGame));
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get => error;
        private set
        {
            error = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Error));
        }
    }
    public string URL
    {
        get => url;
        set
        {
            url = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(URL));
        }
    }

    public bool OpenDownloadedFile { get; set; }

    public double ProgressBarValue
    {
        get => progressBarValue;
        set
        {
            progressBarValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ProgressBarValue));
        }
    }

    public string BytesTotal
    {
        get => bytesTotal;
        private set
        {
            bytesTotal = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BytesTotal));
        }
    }

    public string BytesReceived
    {
        get => bytesReceived;
        private set
        {
            bytesReceived = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BytesReceived));
        }
    }

    public string Speed
    {
        get => speed;
        private set
        {
            speed = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Speed));
        }
    }

    public string Time
    {
        get => time;
        private set
        {
            time = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Time));
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand DownloadCommand =>
        downloadCommand ??
        (downloadCommand = new RelayCommand(DownloadButton_Click));

    public RelayCommand CancelCommand =>
        cancelCommand ??
        (cancelCommand = new RelayCommand(CancelButton_Click));

    private void DownloadButton_Click(object obj)
    {
        if (url == null && url == "") return;
        try
        {
            SelectedGame.DownloadFile(url, OpenDownloadedFile);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Error = e.Message;
        }
    }

    private void CancelButton_Click(object obj)
    {
        if (url != null || url != "")
            SelectedGame.CancelDownloading();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
    private static string PrettyBytes(double bytes)
    {
        if (bytes < 1024)
            return bytes + "Bytes";
        if (bytes < Math.Pow(1024, 2))
            return (bytes / 1024).ToString("F" + 2) + "Kilobytes";
        if (bytes < Math.Pow(1024, 3))
            return (bytes / Math.Pow(1024, 2)).ToString("F" + 2) + "Megabytes";
        if (bytes < Math.Pow(1024, 4))
            return (bytes / Math.Pow(1024, 5)).ToString("F" + 2) + "Gygabytes";
        return (bytes / Math.Pow(1024, 4)).ToString("F" + 2) + "terabytes";
    }

    public static string DownloadingSpeed(long received, TimeSpan time)
    {
        return ((double)received / 1024 / 1024 / time.TotalSeconds).ToString("F" + 2) + " megabytes/sec";
    }
    public static string DownloadingTime(long received, long total, TimeSpan time)
    {
        var receivedD = (double) received;
        var totalD = (double) total;
        return ((totalD / (receivedD / time.TotalSeconds)) - time.TotalSeconds).ToString("F" + 1) + "sec";
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Window x:Class="DownloadingFiles.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DownloadingFiles"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainVM/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="4">
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding URL, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            FontSize="40" Width="424"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Content="DOWNLOAD" FontSize="30" FontFamily="./#Sochi2014" Command="{Binding DownloadCommand}" Canvas.Left="429" Canvas.Top="-2" Width="157"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Error, Mode=OneWay}" FontFamily="./#Sochi2014" Height="45" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Canvas.Left="401" Canvas.Top="123" Width="184" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="30" Content="Open after downloading"
                  IsChecked="{Binding OpenDownloadedFile, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontFamily="./#Sochi2014" Canvas.Left="15" Canvas.Top="80"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Content="CANCEL" FontSize="30" FontFamily="./#Sochi2014" Command ="{Binding CancelCommand}" Canvas.Left="429" Canvas.Top="50" Width="157"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Time, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="30" FontFamily="./#Sochi2014" Height="40" Width="69" Canvas.Left="310" Canvas.Top="277" RenderTransformOrigin="2.284,1.56"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Content="{Binding Speed, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="30" FontFamily="./#Sochi2014" Height="40" Width="193" Canvas.Left="15" Canvas.Top="277"/>
        <ProgressBar Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Value="{Binding ProgressBarValue}"  Foreground="#AAA1C8" Height="75" Width="424" Canvas.Left="15" Canvas.Top="335"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="3" FontSize="30" FontFamily="./#Sochi2014" Content="{Binding ProgressBarValue}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Canvas.Left="230" Canvas.Top="339"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Content="{Binding BytesReceived, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="30" FontFamily="./#Sochi2014" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="448" Canvas.Top="299" Width="137"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Content="{Binding BytesTotal, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="30" FontFamily="./#Sochi2014" Height="44" Canvas.Left="448" Canvas.Top="344" Width="137" />
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Height="40" Width="186" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="202"/>
    </Canvas>

    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Games}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGame, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="0" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

RelayCommand:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
    {
        if (execute == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter ?? "<N/A>");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/markodt/SGet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind to the `SelectedGame` property. But to fully enable the switching between the downloading items you would have to refactor your code and move download specific attributes (e.g. progress, speed) into a separate class for each download (because `SelectedGame` doesn't expose all required attributes). This way each game or download item has it's own exposes its own download related information to the view.

So I introduced a `DownloadItem` class that encapsulates donwnload related attributes or data. This class represents your game or download items that you can select in the `ListView`:

```
class DownloadItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public DownloadItem()
  {
    this.DisplayBytesTotal = string.Empty;
    this.Url = string.Empty;
    this.DownloadSpeed = string.Empty;
    this.ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
    this.Name = string.Empty;
    this.ProgressBytesRead = string.Empty;
  }

  [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private string name;    
  public string Name
  {
    get => this.name;
    set
    {
      if (value == this.name) return;
      this.name = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private string url;    
  public string Url
  {
    get => this.url;
    set
    {
      if (value == this.url) return;
      this.url = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private double progress;    
  public double Progress
  {
    get => this.progress;
    set
    {
      this.progress = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private bool isOpenAfterDownloadEnabled;    
  public bool IsOpenAfterDownloadEnabled
  {
    get => this.isOpenAfterDownloadEnabled;
    set
    {
      this.isOpenAfterDownloadEnabled = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private string progressBytesRead;    
  public string ProgressBytesRead
  {
    get => this.progressBytesRead;
    set
    {
      if (value == this.progressBytesRead) return;
      this.progressBytesRead = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private long bytesTotal;    
  public long BytesTotal
  {
    get => this.bytesTotal;
    set
    {
      if (value == this.bytesTotal) return;
      this.bytesTotal = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private string displayBytesTotal;    
  public string DisplayBytesTotal
  {
    get => this.displayBytesTotal;
    set
    {
      if (value == this.displayBytesTotal) return;
      this.displayBytesTotal = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private string downloadSpeed;    
  public string DownloadSpeed
  {
    get => this.downloadSpeed;
    set
    {
      if (value == this.downloadSpeed) return;
      this.downloadSpeed = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private string timeElapsed;    
  public string TimeElapsed
  {
    get => this.timeElapsed;
    set
    {
      if (value == this.timeElapsed) return;
      this.timeElapsed = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private string errorMessage;    
  public string ErrorMessage
  {
    get => this.errorMessage;
    set
    {
      if (value == this.errorMessage) return;
      this.errorMessage = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

Then, to encapsulate the download behavior, I modified the your `Model` class and renamed it to `Downloader`. Each `DownloadItem` is associated with one `Downloader`. Therefore the `Downloader` now handles the progress of its associated `DownloadItem` by itself and updates the `DownloadItem` accordingly:

```
class Downloader
{
  public DownloadItem CurrentDownloadItem { get; set; }
  public WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
  public Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
  public event Action<long> FileSizeChanged;
  public event Action<long, TimeSpan> DownloadBytesChanged;
  public event Action<double> ProgressPercentageChanged;
  public event Action DownloadComplete;


  public void DownloadFile(DownloadItem gameToDownload)
  {
    this.CurrentDownloadItem = gameToDownload;
    if (webClient.IsBusy)
      throw new Exception("The client is busy");

    var startDownloading = DateTime.UtcNow;
    webClient.Proxy = null;
    if (!SelectFolder(
      Path.GetFileName(this.CurrentDownloadItem.Url) + Path.GetExtension(this.CurrentDownloadItem.Url),
      out var filePath))
    {
      DownloadingError();
      return;
    }

    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, args) =>
    {
      UpdateProgressPercentage(args.ProgressPercentage);
      UpdateFileSize(args.TotalBytesToReceive);
      UpdateProgressBytesRead(args.BytesReceived, DateTime.UtcNow - startDownloading);
      if (args.ProgressPercentage >= 100 && this.CurrentDownloadItem.IsOpenAfterDownloadEnabled)
        Process.Start(filePath);
    };
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += OnDownloadCompleted;
    stopWatch.Start();
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(this.CurrentDownloadItem.Url), filePath);
  }

  public void CancelDownloading()
  {
    webClient.CancelAsync();
    webClient.Dispose();
    DownloadComplete?.Invoke();
  }

  private string PrettyBytes(double bytes)
  {
    if (bytes < 1024)
      return bytes + "Bytes";
    if (bytes < Math.Pow(1024, 2))
      return (bytes / 1024).ToString("F" + 2) + "Kilobytes";
    if (bytes < Math.Pow(1024, 3))
      return (bytes / Math.Pow(1024, 2)).ToString("F" + 2) + "Megabytes";
    if (bytes < Math.Pow(1024, 4))
      return (bytes / Math.Pow(1024, 5)).ToString("F" + 2) + "Gygabytes";
    return (bytes / Math.Pow(1024, 4)).ToString("F" + 2) + "terabytes";
  }

  private string DownloadingSpeed(long received, TimeSpan time)
  {
    return ((double) received / 1024 / 1024 / time.TotalSeconds).ToString("F" + 2) + " megabytes/sec";
  }

  private string DownloadingTime(long received, long total, TimeSpan time)
  {
    var receivedD = (double) received;
    var totalD = (double) total;
    return ((totalD / (receivedD / time.TotalSeconds)) - time.TotalSeconds).ToString("F" + 1) + "sec";
  }

  private void OnDownloadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs asyncCompletedEventArgs)
  {
  }

  private void UpdateProgressPercentage(double percentage)
  {
    this.CurrentDownloadItem.Progress = percentage;
  }

  private void UpdateProgressBytesRead(long bytes, TimeSpan time)
  {
    this.CurrentDownloadItem.ProgressBytesRead = PrettyBytes(bytes);
    this.CurrentDownloadItem.DownloadSpeed = DownloadingSpeed(bytes, time);
    this.CurrentDownloadItem.TimeElapsed = DownloadingTime(bytes, this.CurrentDownloadItem.BytesTotal, time);
  }

  protected virtual void UpdateFileSize(long bytes)
  {
    this.CurrentDownloadItem.DisplayBytesTotal = PrettyBytes(bytes);
  }

  private void DownloadingError()
    => this.CurrentDownloadItem.ErrorMessage = "Downloading Error";

  private static bool SelectFolder(string fileName, out string filePath)
  {
    var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
    {
      InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\MusicMonkey\Downloads",
      FileName = fileName,
      Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*",
    };
    filePath = "";
    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() != true)
      return false;
    filePath = saveFileDialog.FileName;
    return true;
  }
}
```

I highly recommend to move the `SaveFileDialog` and the interaction to the view. This way you would eliminate view model dependencies to view related operations or logic.

The refactored view model would look as followed:

```
class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private RelayCommand downloadCommand;
  private RelayCommand cancelCommand;
  private DownloadItem selectedGame;
  public ObservableCollection<DownloadItem> Games { get; set; }

  private Dictionary<DownloadItem, Downloader> DownloaderMap { get; set; }

  public TestViewModel()
  {
    this.Games = new ObservableCollection<DownloadItem>();
    this.DownloaderMap = new Dictionary<DownloadItem, Downloader>();

    var game1 = new DownloadItem() {Name = "Name1"};
    this.Games.Add(game1);
    this.DownloaderMap.Add(game1, new Downloader());
    var game2 = new DownloadItem() {Name = "Name2"};
    this.Games.Add(game2);
    this.DownloaderMap.Add(game2, new Downloader());
  }

  public DownloadItem SelectedGame
  {
    get => selectedGame;
    set
    {
      if (value == selectedGame)
        return;
      selectedGame = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedGame));
    }
  }

  public RelayCommand DownloadCommand =>
    downloadCommand ??
    (downloadCommand = new RelayCommand((param) => DownloadButton_Click(param), (param) => true));

  public RelayCommand CancelCommand =>
    cancelCommand ??
    (cancelCommand = new RelayCommand((param) => CancelButton_Click(param), (param) => true));

  private void DownloadButton_Click(object obj)
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.SelectedGame.Url))
      return;

    if (this.DownloaderMap.TryGetValue(this.SelectedGame, out Downloader downloader))
    {
      downloader.DownloadFile(this.SelectedGame);
    }
  }

  private void CancelButton_Click(object obj)
  {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.SelectedGame.Url) &&
        this.DownloaderMap.TryGetValue(this.SelectedGame, out Downloader downloader))
    {
      downloader.CancelDownloading();
    }
  }
}
```

Last step I updated the view's bindings to the new properties:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Canvas Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
          Grid.RowSpan="4">
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
             Text="{Binding SelectedGame.Url, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             FontSize="40"
             Width="424" />
    <Button Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Content="DOWNLOAD"
            FontSize="30"
            FontFamily="./#Sochi2014"
            Command="{Binding DownloadCommand}"
            Canvas.Left="429"
            Canvas.Top="-2"
            Width="157" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1"
           Grid.Column="2"
           Content="{Binding SelectedGame.ErrorMessage, Mode=OneWay}"
           FontFamily="./#Sochi2014"
           Height="45"
           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
           Canvas.Left="401"
           Canvas.Top="123"
           Width="184" />
    <CheckBox Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              FontSize="30"
              Content="Open after downloading"
              IsChecked="{Binding SelectedGame.IsOpenAfterDownloadEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              FontFamily="./#Sochi2014"
              Canvas.Left="15"
              Canvas.Top="80" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Content="CANCEL"
            FontSize="30"
            FontFamily="./#Sochi2014"
            Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
            Canvas.Left="429"
            Canvas.Top="50"
            Width="157" />
    <Label Grid.Row="2"
           Grid.Column="1"
           Content="{Binding SelectedGame.TimeElapsed, Mode=OneWay}"
           FontSize="30"
           FontFamily="./#Sochi2014"
           Height="40"
           Width="69"
           Canvas.Left="310"
           Canvas.Top="277"
           RenderTransformOrigin="2.284,1.56" />
    <Label Grid.Row="2"
           Grid.Column="3"
           Content="{Binding SelectedGame.DownloadSpeed, Mode=OneWay}"
           FontSize="30"
           FontFamily="./#Sochi2014"
           Height="40"
           Width="193"
           Canvas.Left="15"
           Canvas.Top="277" />
    <ProgressBar Grid.Row="3"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                 Value="{Binding SelectedGame.Progress}"
                 Foreground="#AAA1C8"
                 Height="75"
                 Width="424"
                 Canvas.Left="15"
                 Canvas.Top="335" />
    <Label Grid.Row="3"
           FontSize="30"
           FontFamily="./#Sochi2014"
           Content="{Binding SelectedGame.Progress}"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
           Canvas.Left="230"
           Canvas.Top="339" />
    <Label Grid.Row="3"
           Grid.Column="3"
           Content="{Binding SelectedGame.ProgressBytesRead, Mode=OneWay}"
           FontSize="30"
           FontFamily="./#Sochi2014"
           Height="40"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Canvas.Left="448"
           Canvas.Top="299"
           Width="137" />
    <Label Grid.Row="3"
           Grid.Column="3"
           Content="{Binding SelectedGame.DisplayBytesTotal, Mode=OneWay}"
           FontSize="30"
           FontFamily="./#Sochi2014"
           Height="44"
           Canvas.Left="448"
           Canvas.Top="344"
           Width="137" />
    <Label Content="{Binding SelectedGame.Name}"
           Height="40"
           Width="186"
           Canvas.Left="22"
           Canvas.Top="202" />
  </Canvas>

  <ListBox x:Name="ListBox" Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Grid.RowSpan="4"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Games}"
           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGame, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
           SelectedIndex="0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock FontSize="20"
                     Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

To enhance the view you could consider about creating a collection with the current active downloads and bind it to an `ItemsControl`. When you now move the layout into a `ItemTemplate` you would be able to display the progress for each download simultaneously without any switching necessary.

To sum it up: your design doesn't allow you to achieve your goal or makes it too complicated. After splitting your code into responsibilities and encapsulating certain behavior and attributes your goal is much easier to achieve. This is just a raw example of how a improved design can help to be more flexible when implementing requirements.